# How can I keep track of Keras training progress in a Jupyter notebook to which I have reconnected?

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

There are various ways to show training progress with Keras callbacks. One might use tqdm in the following way:

```
class EpochProgressBar(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.total_epochs = self.params['epochs']
        self.current_epoch = 0
        self.pbar = tqdm_notebook(total=self.total_epochs, desc='epochs')
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.current_epoch += 1
        #print(f'epoch {self.current_epoch} of epochs {self.total_epochs}')
        self.pbar.update(1);
```

```
callbacks = [EpochProgressBar()]
```

Even simpler, one might have a simple text-based progress output that is cleared with each loop:

```
class ProgressStatus(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    # callbacks = [ProgressStatus()]
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.total_epochs = self.params['epochs']
        self.current_epoch = 0
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.current_epoch += 1
        clear_output(wait=True)
        print(f'epoch {self.current_epoch} of epochs {self.total_epochs}')
```

```
callbacks = [ProgressStatus()]
```

When I reload the notebook window (or disconnect from the notebook and then reconnect to it via SSH and open it again in the browser) I lose the constantly-updating output. It is just frozen. How can I ensure that the output keeps updating when I reconnect to the notebook or reload the page?

(I am aware of the likes of TensorBoard -- I am wanting the progress to continue to be displayed dynamically in the notebook).

Comment: Hey @BlandCorporation - because this is really a question about software (being used to run statistics / machine learning) and not about machine learning, it's not on topic for this site. I've proposed to move it to StackOverflow, where I think it would be a quite reasonable question.

Comment: @Dougal Fair enough.